# How do I create an HTTP server with Node.js on a DreamHost VPS running Apache?

Tags: node.js, http, dreamhost

I've installed Node.js on my DreamHost VPS (basically a virtual machine), but my VPS hosts a lot of other websites using Apache. How can I bind an HTTP listener to a specific domain using Node.js, so that when I visit "mynodejsdomain.com", I get responses from my Node.js code, but when I visit "myotherdomain.com", I get responses from Apache/PHP?

Comment: Through mod_proxy I think. Redirect the node-domain to a different port than 80 where you run node on.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, and DreamHost actually does this for you: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Proxy_Server - Post this as an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: Don't care, happy to help, self-answer if you will. :-)

Comment: No question should go unanswered on SO. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to tell Apache to forward the requests for that domain, and DreamHost provides a nice frontend for mod_proxy:

http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Proxy_Server

Thanks, [CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster)!